# how to find index of a string inside the string

Tags: python, string, if-statement

Hey (bad english) so i am working on a function that is going to check if a string1 is inside another string2. i do belive i have accomplished this, but after that, i am trying to find the index of where the string2 was found in the string1. if the string is not in the string at all it will return (-1). i have tried googling around and looking for asnwers i have seen someone use s.find(), but for somehow can't use it. Therefor i am asking here for some help
this is how i have come:

```
def contains_string(str1, str2):
    if str1 in str2:
       print(str1.find(str2))
    else:
       print("-1")
    return

str1 = Ronaldo
str2 = Ron
str3 = Messi
print(contains_string(str1, str2))
print(contains_string(str1, str3))
#outcome should be:
#3    <- because Ron goes to index 3 in str1
#-1
```

i think i am really close, but i am not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a small logic problem.
When you use `contains_string(str1,str2)`, you want to see if for example "Ron" is in "Ronaldo'. But you are checking this:

```
if str1 in str2:
```

This is basically saying is "Ronaldo" in "Ron" which is false.
Thus, you'll only need to change that line

```
if str2 in str1:
```

Hope that helps!